# Ionic mostrar lautitude e longitude na view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Não estou conseguindo mostrar na view minha localização, mas usando o console.log(long) eu consigo ver pelo console minha localização. onde posso estar errando?`
.controller('GeoCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaGeolocation) {

```
var posOptions = {
    timeout: 10000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};
$cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude
        var long = position.coords.longitude
        console.log(long);
        $scope.latitude = lat;
        $scope.longitude = long;
    }, function (err) {
        // error
    });


var watchOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
};

var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
watch.then(
    null,
    function (err) {
        // error
    },
    function (position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude
        var long = position.coords.longitude
        $scope.latitude = lat;
        $scope.longitude = long;
    });


watch.clearWatch();
// OR
$cordovaGeolocation.clearWatch(watch)
    .then(function (result) {
        // success
    }, function (error) {
        // error
    });
```

});

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Geolocalização</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="GeoCtrl">
        {{latitude}},{{longitude}}
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Comment: Tenta colocar um `$scope.$apply();` dentro da tua função que traz a posição, abaixo do `$scope.longitude = long`

Comment: @joaopaulosantosalmeida está dando um erro assim ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, estava com erro  no código que peguei como base no site do ngCordova, retirei essa parte que estava errada pois não estava usando ai o controller ficou assim.

```
.controller('GeoCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaGeolocation) {

var posOptions = {
    timeout: 10000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false
};
$cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude
        var long = position.coords.longitude
        $scope.latitude = lat;
        $scope.longitude = long;
        alert($scope.latitude);
        alert($scope.longitude);


    }, function (err) {
        // error
    });


var watchOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
};

var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
watch.then(
    null,
    function (err) {
        // error
    },
    function (position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude
        var long = position.coords.longitude
        $scope.latitude = lat;
        $scope.longitude = long;
    });
```

});